# Can I iterate through files with a certain extension from the vim command line?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

Pretty frequently while I'm using vim, I'll run into something like this. I want to edit a specific `.txt` file, that is under `~/Documents/myProj`, but I don't remember the name of the file. So I will do something like this:

```
:e ~/Documents/myProj/<tab><tab><tab><tab>...
```

until the file I recognize comes up. This is OK-ish, but it can sometimes be inconvenient when I have a lot of other files with different extensions, or even subdirectories in the same directory. Is there any way I could do something like:

```
:e ~/Documents/myProj/*.txt<tab><tab><tab><tab>...
```

and only have vim suggest the files that match the `.txt` extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is exactly how Vim behaves.

```
:e ~/Documents/myProj/*.txt<tab><tab><tab><tab>...
```

You may want to turn on `'wildmenu'` in your `vimrc` so you can see the list or use `<c-d>`.

```
set wildmenu
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'wildmenu'
:h c_CTRL-D
:h cmdline-completion
```

Comment: Huh. Well now I feel really silly. That's what I get for asking a question before I try it out myself. And `wildmenu` is super useful too.